# inputImage.getByteBuffer() is null when using AndroidX Camera with MLKit

Tags: android, androidx, firebase-mlkit, firebase-machine-learning

This is the code from my Activity class:

```
    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        _cpf = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);
        _cpf.addListener(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = _cpf.get();
                    bindImageAnalysis(cameraProvider);
                } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));
    }

    private void bindImageAnalysis(@NonNull ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider) {
        ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis =
                new ImageAnalysis.Builder().setTargetResolution(new Size(640, 360))
                        .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST).build();
        imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), new ImageAnalysis.Analyzer() {
            @Override
            public void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy ip) {
                processImage(ip.getImage(), ip.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees());
                ip.close();
            }
        });
        CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK).build();
        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner)this, cameraSelector, imageAnalysis);
    }
```

On every `analyze` callback, MLKit indicates that
`InputImage.fromMediaImage(ip.getImage(),ip.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees()).getByteBuffer()` is null. How should I interpret this? Does this always mean that the image is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the fact that I was `.close()`ng prematurely. `PoseDetector` processing is asynchronous so `processImage` is being called and immediately after `ip.close()`. When `ip.close()` is called, processImage is still working so this is the reason behind `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.nio.ByteBuffer android.media.Image$Plane.getBuffer()`. Instead of using `.close()` inside the `analyze` method, it should be invoked at the end of `OnSuccessListener` or `OnSuccessListener`.

Here is the full [example](https://github.com/amulet-opensource/cameraxmlkit).

Answer (score 1):

inputImage.getByteBuffer() is an internal method which is not designed for public usage. This method will only return when you use a bytebuffer or byte array to construct the image. If you need to use a bytebuffer from your android media image, you will need to do the conversion on your own.

Also, we made some changes to Firebase ML Kit to better distinguish the on-device APIs from cloud based APIs. "[ML Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/guides)"(without firebase branding) contains all the on-device APIs. [Here's](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration) the migration guide from firebase mlkit to mlkit. All further improvements and new APIs will be released only with the new ML Kit.

Comment: In the ```OnFailureListener``` I am getting the ```com.google.mlkit.common.MlKitException: Internal error has occurred when executing ML Kit tasks```. The error.getCause() returns ```java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.nio.ByteBuffer android.media.Image$Plane.getBuffer()' on a null object reference```. To put this into perspective, this error occurs while using the```InputImage.fromMediaImage()``` constructor.

Comment: I included the ```firebase-machine-learning``` tag just to increase the chance this is going to get answered. I am using the MLKit version without firebase branding.